# GoLand not auto-importing local project packages

Tags: go

I am not sure if this behavior is intended, but GoLand appears to NOT auto-import **local project packages** when referenced.

GoLand has intellisense for the package and package methods. However, after adding the method for a **local package**, GoLand just complains that it is an "unresolved reference". Until I manually import the package myself.

I have all of my import optimization settings enabled. GoLand auto-imports ALL github and system packages, just not my **local project packages**.

Is there any way to enable auto-import for local packages? Or must I manually import them myself?

Thank you

[image]

[image: Not auto-importing]

[image: Manually imported]

Comment: You cannot use relative paths in GOPATH. Step through [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for complete examples

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good practice to use local imports this way. Instead, link to the package through your GOPATH, i.e. `github.com/your_github_username/your_project_dir/utilities`.

Assuming project directory:

```
$GOPATH/
  |
  src/
   |
   github.com/
     |
     your_github_username/
          |
          your_project_dir/
              |utilities
          main.go
```

project: `github.com/your_github_username/your_project_dir`

package: `github.com/your_github_username/your_project_dir/utilities`

Following [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library) standard your local package should import without issue.